# How can I batch a tensorflow dataset without loading all the data into memory simultaneously?

Tags: python, database, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am developing a Speech Recognition Model using TensorFlow, and I have a **directory structure** for my dataset. Within the `./dataset` directory, I have **subdirectories** for validation, training, and testing (`dev-clean`, `test-clean`, `train-clean-100`). Each of these subdirectories contains several directories with a unique ID. Inside each of these directories, there are two files: `audio.wav` and `text.txt`.

I want to perform preprocessing on the audio and text data on the fly while loading the dataset. Here is my current dataset loading function:

```py
def build_dataset(self, path: str = "./dataset/train-clean-100") -> Any:
    audio_files = []
    text_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file == "audio.wav":
                audio_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
            elif file == "text.txt":
                text_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    audio_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(audio_files)
    audio_dataset = audio_dataset.map(
        self.preprocess_audio, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(text_files)
    text_dataset = text_dataset.map(
        self.preprocess_text, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((audio_dataset, text_dataset))
    return dataset

def preprocess_audio(self, audio_path: str) -> tf.Tensor:
    audio = tf.io.read_file(audio_path)
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio, desired_samples=20000)
    return audio

def preprocess_text(self, text_path: tf.Tensor) -> Any:
    texts = tf.io.read_file(text_path)
    tokens = self.vectorizer(texts)
    return tokens
```

This implementation works fine when I don't use batching (loading a single item). However, when I call .batch() on the dataset, my development environment (VSCode) and python crash. I suspect this is due to the entire dataset being loaded into memory instead of just the file names.

How can I efficiently batch this dataset while still loading the data on the fly, rather than loading everything into memory at once?